# Is there a way to check the affixes of champions without my follower charging them?

Tags: diablo-iii

I usually play DH with the Templar and the most important thing for me to check is if the champions have Damage Reflect or if the Minions are Invulnerable before I start shooting.

Somehow the radius in which the affixes are displayed is very small, even if I see them in the distance hovering over them does not show their attributes.

I tried on several occasions to look at their affixes while slowly walking towards them, but as soon as they are displayed my stupid follower charges them, which is pretty bothersome, as I want them to be max distance before I start shooting.

Just to be clear:

- I need my follower for the extra Magic Find.
- I need to know if the champions have Damage Reflect so I can use Shadow Power or SS before my projectiles hit, otherwise I kill myself in 3-4 hits.
- I cannot use these abilities on every pack, as if they have different affixes I need to spend my Discipline on other skills.

Comment: Is it a requirement that your follower be the Templar?

Comment: Just a tip - You can always lead with a slow-moving projectile like Ball Lightning or Nether Tentacles, check the affix before they land, and hit SS at the last second if needed.

Comment: Maybe you could spec your templar differently, so he doesn't have the Charge ability (though it is kinda useful).

Comment: @bwarner Yes. Yes it is. The others are useless.

Comment: Blizzard is also aware of the issue of followers and pets attacking idle packs (and treasure goblins), and have indicated that they're looking at various solutions. Soon(tm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you the basic and most straightforward answer there is.
**No**. It is not implemented as a game mechanic in diablo 3 that you can place a follower on something like passive, aggressive or defensive stances (like in many other games).

I did however, see quite a lot of forum posts suggesting this should be implemented. Hence I think that after all bugs, exploits and balance issues are solved blizzard will implement such a system. But as of now, you are going to have to deal with it.

I can however, suggest some things which might help.

- A higher screen resolution, yes I know it sounds stupid but.. with a big screen you can see much more then with a smaller screen. Obviously, this isn't the most viable option, but it's one option..
- Try to avoid abilities on your summoner which allow your follower to move faster (i.e. the templar charge), or have a big range.
- I don't see how it's an issue if the follower starts attacking, it will only make the monsters attack him, which allows you to quickly check the affixes and decide what to do. This does mean you probably have to give your follower some items to make him a bit more survivable (aka not get one shot, which they really like to do it seems).

I'm sorry I can not be a much more help, since I have also got a lot a friends who also don't stand a chance to the reflect damage packs I know why this is an issue.

I do hope the answer helped you in some way, but for now we are simply going to have to deal with it.

Comment: If your only reason for having a follower is increased magic find, it shouldn't matter whether he gets one shotted.

Comment: Indeed it does not, but.. the question was whether it was possible to check affixes of elite packs before your follower charges in. If the follower charges in, and he gets one shot, you do not have time to check the affixes and get to max range. If he survives for a few seconds you might have time for this.

Comment: Resolution is does not affect what you can see - aspect ratio of your display does - see http://diablo.incgamers.com/gallery/data/632/D3_Distance_Map.jpg if you want to see more, use a 16:9 display.  The practical approach is to not use a follower, and if you detect an elite pack, go back to town and add your follower when you're ready to engage the pack.

Comment: I don't think the follower getting one-shotted is the problem. DH characters tend(ed) to have really high DPS even when other gear and stats were low. This meant 2 or 3 damage reflected shots could kill the *player* before they even realized what was happening, since it is easy to fire 2-3 shots before the first one lands.